# Is there a difference between "make a choice", "make a decision" and "choose a decision"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, word-meaning

Is there any difference either in usage or in meaning between the following:

1- **(Make a choice)**, as in: *Making a choice is easy.*

2- **(Make a decision)**, as in: *We make thousands of decisions a day.*

3- **(Choose a decision)**, as in: *Choosing your decision will need skill.*

Thank you.

Comment: "choose a decision" is generally wrong, unless there is a multiple choice test, for example, where they tell you to choose one to answer a question.

Comment: What have you found in a dictionary about the differences between "choice" and "decision", and between "choose" and "decide"?

Answer (score 4):

A "choice" is usually a selection from a number of possibilities. For example, you might choose what to eat from a menu.

"Decision" is a much broader term. Some decisions could have potentially limitless possibilities, such as deciding what career path to take, or deciding what to name a child. However, a 'choice' is *a kind of decision*, so some decisions can be limited.

You would not say "choose a decision". As explained, a choice *is* a decision.

Comment: One might, possibly, be given a list of possible decisions and asked to choose one. But that is a somewhat contrived example..

Comment: @DavidSiegel Very contrived. You are more likely to decide on a choice.